# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Fingerprint not recognizing

Tags: gnome, login, asus, fingerprint-reader, pam

I have enrolled the fingerprint but it doesn't recognize my fingerprint on the login screen. 

**OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Laptop: Asus Zenbook 14 UX430UAR**

I checked if my device is supported or not in [supported list](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html). It is supported:

```
------@-------:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5694 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The result of `fprintd-verify`

```
---------@------------:~$ fprintd-verify
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Listing enrolled fingers:
 - #0: left-index-finger
 - #1: right-index-finger
Verify started!
Verifying: left-index-finger
Verify result: verify-no-match (done)
```

This is the image of the sensor. Capacitance Fingerprint sensor. Top right square
[image]

I have checked that Ubuntu supports the fingerprint sensor. I had windows on this laptop before and with windows hello it worked perfectly. On Ubuntu I'm able to register the fingerprint but during login screen it is not recognizing the fingerprint. I'm sliding my finger across the sensor unlike how i tapped in windows hello authentication.
[image]

Comment: any update to this? I have the exact same problem: supported device, `fprintd-verfiy` working, but gdm3 login doesn'r!

Comment: @roxch Nope, I tried a lot but couldn't find anything working.

Comment: Have the same problem with my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 14ARE05 — on Windows fingerprint device work nicely, on Ubuntu/Fedora — doesn't recognize my fingers at all